# Scala - handle Eithers in property based testing

Tags: scala, property-based-testing

I am creating property based tests for my scala project but I don't know how I should handle Eithers in my generators.
Here's an example.

```
def genCompany: Gen[Company] =
    for {
      letter <- Gen.oneOf('A' to 'Z')
      company = Company.from(letter.toString()) //-> returns Either[Error, Company]
    } yield company
```

Should I change the return type to `Gen[Either[Error, Company]]`?
If so, how would I use this generator inside other generators?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use `company = Company(letter.toString)` instead. `<-` in `company <- ...` is a shorthand or syntactic sugar for map method. [Read more](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting that error right now and couldn't figure out why!